# Is there a way to programmatically expand the sliver app bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

I have used sliver app bar for get expanded and collapsible app bar view, i want to know is there any way that can expand the sliver app bar when user touch on collapse app bar..

Answer (score 0):

use the 'ScrollController', like this codes

```
 CustomScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar()....
        ...
        scrollController.animateTo(offset,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800), curve: Curves.ease);
```